# Add a MySQL field of type "bit" to a FuelPHP model

Tags: mysql, bit, fuelphp, variable-types

My schema has a column that is of type "bit(1)". I haven't found a way that this can be expressed in Fuel. They don't seem to support the "bit" type and can't properly build insert queries.

Is there a way (possibly undocumented) to get Fuel to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... the orm supposedly accepts the bit field.

i have created a model from database. Look my migration script and model, maybe it can help you.

**Model**

```
class Model_Test extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'whatever',
    );

    protected static $_table_name = 'tests';

}
```

**Migration script**

builded from an existing table using the command: oil refine fromdb:model test

```
namespace Fuel\Migrations;

class Create_tests
{
    public function up()
    {
        \DBUtil::create_table('tests', array(
            'id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' => true, 'unsigned' => true),
            'whatever' => array('type' => 'bit'),

        ), array('id'));
    }

    public function down()
    {
        \DBUtil::drop_table('tests');
    }
}
```

In the **controller**, you must be need cast the value as INT

```
$f  = Input::post('whatever_post_field');

$o  = Model_Test::forge(array('whatever' => (int)$f));
$o->save();
```

Comment: You're right, the migration script was properly generated using the `bit` field. However, when I use the view (generated by `oil`) to create a new entry, and I enter a `1` or `0` in the textbox for the bit field, Fuel tells me the input I entered is too long. I assume it's trying to insert it as a string?

Comment: yep, Fuel will interpret the value as string.  You need cast the field, tho save him as integer

Comment: Alternatively, define the correct data_type in the models properties, and use the typing observer on before_save to make sure it's an int before it's saved.